# c# Sorting grid at form load

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0

I would like to sort my grid at form load but Visual Studio is not liking my code. Any help would be appreciated!

```
dataGridView1.Sort(dataGridView1.Columns[0], ListSortDirection.Descending);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work by adding this line to the BindingSource

```
this.carCheckoutBindingSource.Sort = "startMiles DESC";
```

Answer (score 2):

You could sort the data initially before binding it. For example, if you have a `DataTable`, you could do:

```
dataTable.DefaultView.Sort("Cola DESC");
```

And then you bind your data already sorted.

Comment: This is a datagridview binded to a sql table

Comment: @adam355 but how does the data come to the frontend? As a Collection of some business objects, as a DataTable, a DataSet, etc? Whatever the case is, the answer is the same, sort the data initially before binding it.

Comment: I have a dataset called intranetDataSet1. After i ran the wizard this line is populating the datagridview. this.carCheckoutTableAdapter1.Fill(this.intranetDataSet1.carCheckout);

Comment: @adam355 Then try this `intranetDataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView.Sort("YourColumn DESC");` and then `dataGridView1.DataSource=intranetDataSet;`

Comment: I get non-invocable member 'sort' cannot be used like a method

Answer (score 1):

```
private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //bind u r collection to datagridview
            DataGridView1.Sort( new RowComparer( SortOrder.Ascending ) );
        }

private class RowComparer : System.Collections.IComparer
{
    private static int sortOrderModifier = 1;

    public RowComparer(SortOrder sortOrder)
    {
        if (sortOrder == SortOrder.Descending)
        {
            sortOrderModifier = -1;
        }
        else if (sortOrder == SortOrder.Ascending)
        {
            sortOrderModifier = 1;
        }
    }

    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        DataGridViewRow DataGridViewRow1 = (DataGridViewRow)x;
        DataGridViewRow DataGridViewRow2 = (DataGridViewRow)y;

        // Try to sort based on the Last Name column.
        int CompareResult = System.String.Compare(
            DataGridViewRow1.Cells[1].Value.ToString(),
            DataGridViewRow2.Cells[1].Value.ToString());

        // If the Last Names are equal, sort based on the First Name.
        if ( CompareResult == 0 )
        {
            CompareResult = System.String.Compare(
                DataGridViewRow1.Cells[0].Value.ToString(),
                DataGridViewRow2.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
        }
        return CompareResult * sortOrderModifier;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is way over my head. i just have a simple datagridview bound to a sql table by using the wizard.

Comment: @Aadam355 then u will have dataobject as dataset try this DataTable table = dataSet.Tables["tableName"];
        DataView view = table.DefaultView;
        view.Sort = "columnName"; acoording to columnName data will sort

Comment: Thanks. How do i specify ascending or descending?

Comment: It is not sorting for me when I run. Here is my code   DataTable table = intranetDataSet1.Tables["carCheckout"];
            DataView view = table.DefaultView; view.Sort = "startMiles DESC";
            this.carCheckoutTableAdapter1.Fill(this.intranetDataSet1.carCheckout);

Comment: I got it to work by adding this line to the BindingSource

this.carCheckoutBindingSource.Sort = "startMiles DESC";

Comment: i miss :O view.Sort = "columnName DESC"; anyway glad for u r problem has been solved :)

Answer (score 0):

Is the datagridview bound to a collection? If Yes then perform the sort on the collection and rebind the sorted collection to the datagridview

Ex:

```
collection.OrderBy(i=> i.<PropertyName>);
datagridview.DataSource = collection;
```

NOTE:

My collection is of type List.

Comment: the datagridview is bound to a dataset